# Are triangulations with common refinements PL-homeomorphic?

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, discrete-geometry, 3-manifolds, simplicial-complexes, 4-manifolds

Do there exist simplicial triangulations $K_1$ and $K_2$ of a topological manifold $M$ such that $K_1$ and $K_2$ have a common subdivision but they are not PL-homeomorphic? Ideally, I would like an example in dimension 4.

My understanding of a PL-homeomorphism is that there exists a common subdivision $L$ and embeddings $\phi_i$ from $K_i$ to some Euclidean space which takes simplexes of both $K_i$ and of $L$ to linear simplexes. Note that there does exist a triangulation $L$ of the 3-simplex $K$ which contains the trefoil in its 1-skeleton with only 3 edges. As the stick number of the trefoil is 6 there is no embedding $\phi: K \to \mathbb{R}^n$ which is linear on both simplexes of $K$ and $L$.

Any suggested references would also be most welcome.

Comment: I'm confused by your question.  If they have a common refinement, the identity map is a PL homeomorphism between the two PL manifolds.

Comment: Lickorish's paper 'Simplicial moves on complexes and manifolds' works with concrete simplicial complexes which are subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and they are said to be PL-homeomorphic if they have linear subdivisions which are simplicially isomorphic. To work with simplicial triangulations of manifolds then I would need to first get an embedding of the manifold in $\mathbb{R}^n$ which is linear in simplexes of both the triangulation and of the subdivision, before applying Lickorish/Pachner’s theorem. Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Perhaps.  I don't understand the hang-up.   From your perspective, what is the problem with regarding the identity map as the PL-homeomorphism?

Comment: To show that two triangulations with a common subdivision are bistellar equivalent, via Pachner's proof spelled out in Lickorish's paper I need the triangulations to be simplicial complexes in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and subdivisions to be linear subdivisions. The proof relies on inductively slicing along hyperplanes of $\mathbb{R}^n$ along faces of the subdivision to get a common slice subdivision. If I start with two topological triangulations with a common subdivision I would first need to translate it to simplicial complexes in $\mathbb{R}^n$ with a linear subdivision to apply this proof.

Comment: So how do I show that topological simplicial triangulations with a common subdivision are bistellar equivalent?

Comment: Or how do I get an embedding from M to $\mathbb{R} ^n$ which takes both simplexes or K and its subdivision to linear simplexes?

Comment: Apologies, I am not quite certain of what conventions you are using.  Regarding your last question, if you have an embedding from $M$ to $\mathbb R^n$ that sends the simplices of $M$ to linear simplices, then by definition it has to take the subdivision to linear simplices -- a linear map restricted to a subspace is linear.  If you disagree with me, you must be using wildly different definitions compared to what I am used to.

Comment: Sorry for this confusion and thanks for your patience... I guess what I find confusing is what I mentioned in the original question. There is a triangulation (subdivision) of a 3-simplex which contains a trefoil in its 1-skeleton with only 3 edges. If there is an embedding of this 3-simplex in $\mathbb{R}^n$ which sends edges to straight line segments and sends the 3-simplex to a linear 3-simplex then it contradicts the fact that the trefoil has stick number 6. So such an embedding does not exist. Where am I going wrong with this argument?

Comment: When you refer to a "triangulation" of the simplex, are you saying it is a triangulation in the sense of "triangulation of a topological manifold"?   To me that would be a fairly non-standard usage of the term.  A simplex is usually considered a PL object before it would be considered a topological object so a triangulation of that would be a subdivision of it.  But your example would require the triangulation to be non-linearly embedded in the simplex. Am I starting to understand where you are coming from?

Comment: Yes, exactly! So when we talk of a common refinement of topological triangulations $K_1$ and $K_2$ of some topological manifold, don't we simply mean a topological triangulation $L$ where each simplex of $L$ lies in some simplex of $K_1$ and some simplex of $K_2$? Now how can I apply Pachner's theorem here to say that $K_1$ and $K_2$ are related by bistellar moves?

Comment: In Pachner's theorem, the theorem is two triangulations (in the PL sense) of a common PL manifold are related by a sequence of stellar moves, and the stellar moves themselves are each linear refinements.  Your sense of "refinement" people might call "exotic refinement" i.e. you are allowing yourself to depart from the underlying PL structure.

Comment: I see... I thought a simplicial triangulation gives an embedding of the manifold in R^n as a simplicial complex and the stellar moves on this simplicial complex under inverse of this homomorphism are the stellar moves on the triangulation on M. So then are there examples of triangulations which have a common exotic refinement but are not PL homomorphic?

Comment: I almost never deal with manifolds with distinct PL structures, so this is taking me out of my comfort zone a little, in terms of generating examples.  But I imagine the universal source is this: take a topological manifold that admits at least two PL structures.  Take those two triangulations.  That's your example.   Although I don't have a proof ready, I imagine the high-dimensional topological transversality theorems would tell you these triangulations have to be exotic refinements of each other.

Comment: Thanks! So just to be sure I've understood things correctly can you check that the following statements are correct: 1. A simplicial triangulation of a manifold gives an identification of the manifold with the total space of a simplicial complex in R^n. It is called a PL-sphere if this simplicial complex has a linear subdivision which is isomorphic to a linear subdivision of boundary of a linear simplex in R^n. A simplicial triangulation of a manifold where link of each vertex is a PL-sphere is a PL-manifold via this identification with a simplicial complex in R^n.

Comment: 2. Two simplicial triangulations of a manifold may have a common topological subdivision triangulation and yet as PL manifolds they may not be isomorphic.

Comment: 3. If the manifold and the triangulations are smooth then by Whitney's theorem, two such simplicial triangulations do in fact give isomorphic PL-manifolds. I call a triangulation smooth if each simplex is the smooth embedding of a linear simplex in R^n.

Comment: (1) and (2), yes.  (3) you need the caveat that the triangulation has to be smoothly compatible.  Basically, that the simplices are smoothly embedded in the "manifold with cubical corners" sense.

Comment: Thanks Ryan, this really clears things for me!